# SPFx Yeoman Generator Installation Issue

Tags: spfx

When attempting to install Microsoft 365 SPFx Yeoman Generator @1.18.2 the following error message is generated:

"An error occurred while running @microsoft/sharepoint: webpart#writing…Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: C:\Users\Tom’s PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\mode_nodules@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\lib\generators\webpart\templates\none[componentClassName].module.scss”

I’ve uninstalled node.js and retried the following process multiple times, to no avail:

1.) Install Node JS v18.19.1 (Go to nodejs.org; other downloads; previous releases; v18.19.1 releases; node-v18.19.1-x64.msi; follow installation wizard. (do not check additional tools).
2,) Install Yeoman v4.3.1   (Command: npm install -g yo@4.3.1)
3.) Install Gulp v.4.0.2    (Command: npm install -g gulp@4.0.2)
4.) Install SPFx Generator 1.18.2   (Command: npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.18.2)
5.) Prompt Gulp trust dev cert  (Command: gulp trust-dev-cert)